# Recoding variables with R

Tags: r

Recoding variables in R, seems to be my biggest headache. What functions, packages, processes do you use to ensure the best result?

I've found very few useful examples on the Internet that give a one-size-fits-all solution to recoding and I'm interested to see what you guys and gals are using.

Note: This may be a community wiki topic.

Comment: recoding factors, numerical values, binning continuous variables into discrete categories, all of the above (and more)?

Comment: @Chase, the question is intentionally broad as I would like to collect a number of possible solutions to this common problem as possible.

Comment: Brandon Bertelsen, I have only ever heard "recoding" used in the usual sense *"rename categorical labels/ reorder categorical levels/ swap levels <-> labels"*. Never for *"convert continuous variables into discrete categories"*, which is binning, not recoding. Nor for changing cut thresholds or quantiles. You need to state some specific use-cases and show a little sample code or data. Otherwise this is a) way too vague and b) a terrible canonical. By the way Google doesn't either, and [Wikipedia isn't aware of this meaning of 'recoding'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recode_(disambiguation))

Comment: @smci you are welcome to suggest an edit to this 7 year old question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Recoding can mean a lot of things, and is fundamentally complicated.

Changing the levels of a factor can be done using the `levels` function:

```
> #change the levels of a factor
> levels(veteran$celltype) <- c("s","sc","a","l")
```

Transforming a continuous variable simply involves the application of a vectorized function:

```
> mtcars$mpg.log <- log(mtcars$mpg)
```

For binning continuous data look at `cut` and `cut2` (in the hmisc package). For example:

```
> #make 4 groups with equal sample sizes
> mtcars[['mpg.tr']] <- cut2(mtcars[['mpg']], g=4)
> #make 4 groups with equal bin width
> mtcars[['mpg.tr2']] <- cut(mtcars[['mpg']],4, include.lowest=TRUE)
```

For recoding continuous or factor variables into a categorical variable there is `recode` in the car package and `recode.variables` in the Deducer package

```
> mtcars[c("mpg.tr2")] <- recode.variables(mtcars[c("mpg")] , "Lo:14 -> 'low';14:24 -> 'mid';else -> 'high';")
```

If you are looking for a GUI, Deducer implements recoding with the Transform and Recode dialogs:

http://www.deducer.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=Main.TransformVariables

http://www.deducer.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=Main.RecodeVariables

Comment: I also like the `recode` function in the `car` package. It can also be used to map one set of categories onto another set (e.g., when you want to collapse a bunch of small categories into an 'other' category).

Comment: When recoding the levels of a factor, I often use a `dput(levels(var))`, then paste and edit the output before giving him to `levels(var)<-`. I find this quite convenient.

Answer (score 12):

I found `mapvalues` from `plyr` package very handy. Package also contains function `revalue` which is similar to `car:::recode`.

The following example will "recode"

```
> mapvalues(letters, from = c("r", "o", "m", "a", "n"), to = c("R", "O", "M", "A", "N"))
 [1] "A" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "M" "N" "O" "p" "q" "R" "s" "t" "u" "v" "w" "x" "y" "z"
```

Answer (score 10):

I find this very convenient when several values should be transformed (its like doing recodes in Stata):

```
# load package and gen some data
require(car)
x <- 1:10

# do the recoding
x
## [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10

recode(x,"10=1; 9=2; 1:4=-99")
## [1] -99 -99 -99 -99   5   6   7   8   2   1
```

Answer (score 5):

I've found that it can sometimes be easier to convert non numeric factors to character before attempting to change them, for example.

```
df <- data.frame(example=letters[1:26]) 
example <- as.character(df$example)
example[example %in% letters[1:20]] <- "a"
example[example %in% letters[21:26]] <- "b"
```

Also, when importing data, it can be useful to ensure that numbers are actually numeric before attempting to convert:

```
df <- data.frame(example=1:100)
example <- as.numeric(df$example)
example[example < 20] <- 1
example[example >= 20 & example < 80] <- 2
example[example >= 80] <- 3
```

Answer (score 4):

When you want to recode levels of a factor, [`forcats`](http://forcats.tidyverse.org/) might come in handy. You can read [a chapter of R for Data Science](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/factors.html#modifying-factor-levels) for an extensive tutorial, but here is the gist of it.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(forcats)
gss_cat %>%
  mutate(partyid = fct_recode(partyid,
                           "Republican, strong"    = "Strong republican",
                           "Republican, weak"      = "Not str republican",
                           "Independent, near rep" = "Ind,near rep",
                           "Independent, near dem" = "Ind,near dem",
                           "Democrat, weak"        = "Not str democrat",
                           "Democrat, strong"      = "Strong democrat",
                           "Other"                 = "No answer",
                           "Other"                 = "Don't know",
                           "Other"                 = "Other party"
  )) %>%
  count(partyid)
#> # A tibble: 8 × 2
#>                 partyid     n
#>                  <fctr> <int>
#> 1                 Other   548
#> 2    Republican, strong  2314
#> 3      Republican, weak  3032
#> 4 Independent, near rep  1791
#> 5           Independent  4119
#> 6 Independent, near dem  2499
#> # ... with 2 more rows
```

You can even let R decide what categories (factor levels) to merge together.

> Sometimes you just want to lump together all the small groups to make a plot or table simpler. That’s the job of fct_lump(). [...] The default behaviour is to progressively lump together the smallest groups, ensuring that the aggregate is still the smallest group.

```
gss_cat %>%
  mutate(relig = fct_lump(relig, n = 10)) %>%
  count(relig, sort = TRUE) %>%
  print(n = Inf)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>        relig     n
#>       <fctr> <int>
#> 1 Protestant 10846
#> 2      Other 10637
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider this sample data.

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 5:1)
df
#  a b
#1 1 5
#2 2 4
#3 3 3
#4 4 2
#5 5 1
```

Here are two options -

**1. `case_when` :**

For single column -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(a = case_when(a == 1 ~ 'a', 
                       a == 2 ~ 'b', 
                       a == 3 ~ 'c', 
                       a == 4 ~ 'd', 
                       a == 5 ~ 'e'))

#  a b
#1 a 5
#2 b 4
#3 c 3
#4 d 2
#5 e 1
```

For multiple columns -

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(c(a, b), ~case_when(. == 1 ~ 'a', 
                                    . == 2 ~ 'b', 
                                    . == 3 ~ 'c', 
                                    . == 4 ~ 'd', 
                                    . == 5 ~ 'e')))

#  a b
#1 a e
#2 b d
#3 c c
#4 d b
#5 e a
```

**2. `dplyr::recode` :**

For single column -

```
df %>%
  mutate(a = recode(a, '1' = 'a', '2' = 'b', '3' = 'c', '4' = 'd', '5' = 'e'))
```

For multiple columns -

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(c(a, b), 
         ~recode(., '1' = 'a', '2' = 'b', '3' = 'c', '4' = 'd', '5' = 'e')))
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a lookup vector using *setNames*, then match on name:

```
# iris as an example data
table(iris$Species)
# setosa versicolor  virginica 
#     50         50         50

x <- setNames(c("x","y","z"), c("setosa","versicolor","virginica"))
iris$Species <- x[ iris$Species ]

table(iris$Species)
#  x  y  z 
# 50 50 50
```