# R and metacharacters: dealing with typos

Tags: r, conditional-statements, factors, levels, recode

The problem:

Suppose we have a really big and messy dataframe. The categories of a variable are difficult to read because of heterogeneous data collecting procedures and typos.

```
> dt

id  var1   
1   blissard
2   Blizzard/Storm
3   storm of snow
4   DUST STORM/BLIZZARD

> class(dt$var1)
[1] "factor"

> levels(dt$var1)
[1] "blissard"               
[2] "Blizzard/Storm"                
[3] "storm of snow"
[4] "DUST STORM/BLIZZARD"
```

The goal:

The dt$var1 levels are four. I would like to make them only two: "blizzard" and "storm".

```
> levels(dt$var1)
[1] "blizzard"               
[2] "blizzard"                
[3] "storm"
[4] "blizzard"
```

NB: Generating a new variable dt$var1b is feasible.

The attempts:

Properly recoding observation [2] is my major issue. The database is quite messy, even with typing errors, hence I have to feed the recoding function with a logical statement with a general regular expression.

I could launch a recode `dt$evty[dt$evty=="(.[Bb][Ll][Ii])+"] <- "blizzard"` , but I do not find a proper procedure to combine indexing and regular expressions.

I could partially reduce the problem with `dt$var1 <- lowercase(dt$var1)`, but it would not solve the problem with typos, and could result in a loss of information.

I found valuable information here:
http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Recoding_data/

and here:
[Recoding variables with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372896/recoding-variables-with-r)

and here on regular expressions:
https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/ItDT/HTML/node84.html

but I do not get how to create a procedure which allow me to deal with typos (i.e. "blissard" instead of "blizzard") without a manual intervention.

I suspect that I am facing the problem from the wrong perspective. Any elegant suggestion on the matter is really appreciated.

Comment: There is no magic bullet for this kind of data cleaning. You automate the best you can, but almost always you end up manually reviewing things. For combining indexing and regexes, you probably are looking for `grepl` and `agrepl`.

Comment: As @joran said, there's no magic bullet. Regarding replacement using regex, perhaps you can do something along the lines of: ` mydf$var1[grepl("[Bb][Ll][Ii]", mydf$var1)] <- "blizzard"` (building on your current approach).

Comment: Thank you guys. I verified and I confirm that you helped me making a step forward. The class of the factor `dt$var1` must be converted to character, in order to be processed by `grepl`. Now I will look for the automatization of the process. Lets move on :)