# Reversing variable values in R

Tags: r, variables, recode

I've seen various questions asked about recoding variables (e.g. [Recoding variables with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372896/recoding-variables-with-r)) but I was wondering if there was an easy way to completely 'flip' the data. I'm currently working with a variable `x` that has a value from 0 to 30 that counts the number of days a patient did NOT spend in the ICU. What I want is the number of days spent in the ICU i.e. if someone didn't spend a single day in the ICU they'd have a value `x=30` but I want a value `x=0` and so and so forth. Obviously I could recode each value individually, but in the interest of saving key strokes and learning a little more about R, I was wondering if there was an easy solution.

Comment: just take 30 -  the nuber of days:  30-(1:30)

Answer (score 3):

You can just invert the data using `(x - max(x)) * -1) + min(x)`

```
inv <- function(x){ ((x - max(x)) * -1) + min(x) }
  icu <- 0:30
    inv(icu)
```

The reason for not simply subtracting is that this works on vectors with negative values as well.

```
( icu <- seq(-1,1,0.1) )
  inv(icu)
```

Comment: I see this is a better solution since works in general. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One minor addition to the function of Jeffrey Evans would be to specify the `na.rm` argument for `max()` and `min()`

```
inv <- function(x){ ((x - max(x, na.rm = TRUE)) * -1) + min(x, na.rm = TRUE) }
```

This way the function will also work in case of missing data.

Answer (score 0):

Addition and subtraction in R are vectorised. This means you can apply a function to a vector and it will return a vector, rather than having to loop over the vector.

```
set.seed(999)
ICU = sample(30) ## number of days in ICU
not_ICU = 30 - ICU ## returns number of days not in ICU
```

Does that  help?

Answer (score 0):

using subtraction:

```
x<-0:30
y<-30-x
```

Comment: simple, yet elegant. I like it