# Recode data in an R dataframe column

Tags: r, dataframe, recode

I have a df with two columns: data and position, where:
data are goals scored (1-10)
and position is the position played (goalie, defence, forward)

I want to add a new column to the df, where if the position is "forward", for the row in a new column to say "good", otherwise, if it's "goalie" or "defence", for the row in the new column to say "bad"
eg.

| data | position | new.column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | goalie | bad |
| 6 | forward | good |
| 9 | defence | bad |
| 5 | forward | good |

Comment: `df$new.column <- ifelse(df$position == "forward", "good", "bad")`. Or the inverse (which might be informative for other needs): `ifelse(df$position %in% c("goalie","defence"), "bad", "good")`. For discussions on `==`-vs-`%in%`, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/15358006/3358272 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/42637099/3358272.

Comment: For more complex recoding, there will be lots of answered questions around here already, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372896/recoding-variables-with-r/5373512#5373512

Comment: @jakub, I think there's likely a better dupe-link out there; that one refers to recoding a numeric column whereas this data is recoding strings.

Comment: @r2evans true. I spent a little while looking and haven't found a really good one. I think pointing out `ifelse()` and `dplyr::recode()` might just be enough though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(data = c(5, 6, 9, 5), 
                 position = c('goalie', 'forward', 'defense', 'forward')) %>% 
mutate(new.column = case_when(
  position == 'forward' ~'good', 
  TRUE ~'bad'
))
```